# Mongoose schema with array of object - is that possible to determine array size as a default in the array field?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm not sure how to describe the question title. please see in example schema to assist me to understand how to define default value in a field that related to the length of the field and will be dynamic each time that field change. (i know thata its seems unlogical due to other methode to get the length , but im try to learn more about schema with this question)

```
const exampleSchema= new mongoose.Schema(
  {
field: [
      {
        someId: String,
        name: String,
        fieldLength: {
default : this.length}
      },
    ]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your schema like this

```
var exampleSchema = new mongooose.Schema({
  field1: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  field2: {
    type: [{
      name: String,
      email: String
    }],
    validate: [checkArrLength, '{PATH} array size is exceeded']
  }
});

function checkArrLength(value) {
  return value.length <= 10;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).